# Why is the NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged event always fired for Teredo pseudo tunneling interface?

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, base-class-library

Im running a Windows Server 2012 as a Guest within an VMWare Workstation. The Guest has two NetworkInterfaces, that are bridged to the Ethernet Cards of the host. The Server is running fine until I started a self written Software, that check the NICs for a address chnange. I subscribe to the NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged Event. The Event is working as expected, but the Teredo pseudo tunneling interface Trigger every Minute a NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged event.

Sure, I can ignore this event if the two briged NICs don't Change their address or status. I want to understand why the event is raised.

Comment: VMWare is a notorious randomizer for operating system behavior.  Contact the vendor for support.